# How close mongoose event listener stream (unwatch)

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have been listening to the event stream with using watch().on

```js
export const BotDbChangeEventEmiter = (
  callback: (change: ChangeStreamDocument<Bot>) => void
) => BotModel.watch<Bot>().on('change', callback);
```

OR

```js
export const BotDbChangeEventEmiter = (
  callback
) => BotModel.watch().on('change', callback);
```

How I can to unsubscribe from the event listener using mongoose?

Answer (score 0):

Use methode `.close()`

```js
// subscribe
const botListener = BotDbChangeEventEmiter(()=>{})


// Here unsubscribe
botListener.close()
```